# SAS and R gives different standard error when fitting Tweedie model

Tags: generalized-linear-model, standard-error, sas, software, tweedie-distribution

I would like to fit a Tweedie GLM to the data. However, even though PROC GENMOD from SAS and glm() from R gives the same coefficient estimates, they give quite different standard error. What it the reason behind this?

Reproducible examples:

Code in R

```r
mydata <- read.csv("https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/data/binary.csv")
mydata$rank <- as.factor(mydata$rank)
mydata$rank <- relevel(mydata$rank, ref = "1")

mytweedie <- glm(admit ~ gre + gpa + rank, data = mydata,
+     family = statmod::tweedie(var.power = 1.5, link.power = 0))
summary(mytweedie)
```

Output from R:

```r
Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -3.4957360  0.7906423  -4.421 1.27e-05 ***
gre          0.0016542  0.0007611   2.173 0.030345 *  
gpa          0.5274319  0.2307913   2.285 0.022825 *  
rank2       -0.3265264  0.2167527  -1.506 0.132754    
rank3       -0.7947102  0.2364447  -3.361 0.000852 ***
rank4       -0.9818197  0.2867970  -3.423 0.000683 ***
```

Code in SAS (after loading the data)

```
PROC GENMOD data=logistic_test DESCENDING;
    CLASS rank(REF = "1");
    MODEL admit = gre gpa rank / DIST=tweedie(p=1.5);
RUN;
```

Output from SAS

```
Parameter    DF    Estimate    Standard Error
Intercept    1     -3.4958     1.1387
gre          1     0.0017      0.0011
gpa          1     0.5274      0.3176
......
```

Why are the standard errors so different? This has nothing to do with the fact that the data set has binary response. I have tested on other data sets as well. It seems to have something to do with Tweedie.

Comment: I am voting to leave this open as it asks about a statistical result from two different packages. I think this is the site most likely to have soemone who can answer.